# OOP PHP price calculator

Tags: php, oop, discount, price, calculation

Code returns undefined variable, I think something is wrong with the function I wrote, it was supposed to divide `$value` and `$splitfee`

```
class Product {
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $price;
    public $splitfee;

    function split() {
        $this->value->splitfee = $this->$value / $splitfee;
    }
}

$product_one = new Product();  
$product_one->name = "potato";
$product_one->price = 100;


$product_two = new Product();
$product_two->name = "tomato";
$product_two->value = 200;
$product_two->splitfee = 200;

$product_three = new Product();
$product_three->name = "auto";
$product_three->price = 300;

echo $product_one->name . " is " . $product_one->price . " $" . "<br />";
echo $product_two->name . " is " . $product_two->split() . " $" . "<br />";
```

Comment: Your function body is incorrect. What is splitfee here?

Comment: it's a fee that was supposed to get divided by product's value, for example 200 / 30 but i see that i set splitfee to 200

Comment: @NadanMarenković http://phpio.net/s/1gkv

Answer (score 0):

You could fix your `split()` method so that it returns a value.  That would allow your inline call to it to print something.

```
function split() {
    return $this->value / $this->splitfee;
}
```

Then the code would print:

`potato is 100 $
tomato is 1 $`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later.

Comment: @nadanarenković great! thank you for selecting this as the solution to help any others that have this issue.

Comment: @nadanarenković please mark this as the solution if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if i understood your logic correctly.

```
class Product {
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $price;
    public $splitfee;

    function split() {
        return $this->value / $this->splitfee;
    }
}
```